# Manually scaling instances of dockerized gitlab-runners

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm having trouble scaling gitlab-runners with docker.
When I run the below container with 1 instance all goes well. The expected number of runners are show as registered in the admin panel. When I scale the service some jobs that are picked up, fail with the following error:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 12.7.1 (003fe500)
  on Docker Runner 638bede4
Using Docker executor with image docker:latest ...
Pulling docker image docker:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:31c774f62a9b520060d72c3c1901facdfdfd0fc4ae7c5e817cdaf6acd456432c for docker:latest ...
Running on runner-638bede4-project-1-concurrent-0 via 9ee0c48a94a3...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): Error: No such container: 2f39fdd536cd4278ecc740479e3976da25f871ab71febc624f7030d59000b029 (executor_docker.go:788:0s)
```

As per the official [link](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/README.html#get-help), this is to be expected because I share the same config.toml. However, when I remove the volume mount to the directory that holds the config.toml, the runners don't pick up a job at all.

My question is: How can I scale runners in a docker setup without sharing the same config.toml?

**update**: after upgrading the version of gitlab the issues subsided somewhat. However, in the official documentation the warning about not sharing the configuration.toml for the runners remains. So my original question still stands.

```
---
version: "3.7"
services:

  gitlab-runner:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    environment:
      http_proxy: someProxy
      https_proxy: someProy
      no_proxy: differentProxy
      CI_SERVER_URL: http://someAddress.redacted:30080/ci
    volumes:
    - gitlab-runner-etc-gitlab:/etc/gitlab-runner:Z
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker

  registration:
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
      restart_policy:
        condition: none
    volumes:
    - gitlab-runner-etc-gitlab:/etc/gitlab-runner:Z
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command:
    - register
    - --non-interactive
    - --locked=false
    - --name=Docker Runner
    - --executor=docker
    - --docker-image=docker:latest
    - --docker-volumes=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    - --docker-volumes=/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    - debug-run
    environment:
      CI_SERVER_URL: http://someAddress.redacted:30080/ci
      REGISTRATION_TOKEN: testtoken1234

volumes:
  gitlab-runner-etc-gitlab:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: nfs
      o: addr=someAddress,rw
      device: ":/var/exports/gitlab-poc/gitlab-runner/etc/gitlab/"
```